# A group associated to a pair of integers $(k,p)$ where $p$ is a prime number

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, prime-numbers

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ be a natural number and $p$ be a prime number with $p\nmid k$.  (We thank Prof. Bartel for his comment on the latter non divisibility condition.)  We denote by $U(p)=\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ the mod-$p$ multiplicative group.  Then we have a natural group homomorphism: $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to U(p)$ which is the unique extension of semi group homomorphism $n\mapsto k^n \pmod p$ defined on semigroup of non negative integers.

**Question:** Is there a group $G$ containing $U(p)$ such that we have an  extension $\psi:\mathbb{Q} \to G$ of $\phi$?

> If the answer is yes, is there a universal group $G(k,p)$ with the following  property:
>
> There is an extension $\psi_{k,p}:\mathbb{Q} \to G_{k,p}$ of $\phi$. Moreover for any other extension $\alpha :\mathbb{Q} \to H\supset U(p)$ of $\phi$, there is a group homomorphism $\beta: G_{k,p} \to H$ with $\alpha =\beta \circ \psi_{k,p}$?

Comment: @AlexB. Yes thank you. I revise it

Answer (score 6):

The group $U(p)$ is the group of units of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, which is known to be cyclic. One can therefore identify $U(p)$ with the subgroup of $(p-1)$-th roots of unity in the group $S^1 = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: \, |z|= 1\}$. Now $k$ has the form $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{p-1}\ell}$ for some integer $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$, and it suffices to set
$$
\psi : \mathbb{Q}\to S^1 \, ; \quad \frac ab \mapsto e^{i\frac ab\frac{2\pi}{p-1}\ell} \, .
$$

I don't have the answer for the universal group $G_{k,p}$ until now.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}$I think we can just unroll your group, and define $G_{k, p} = \mathbb Q \times_{\mathbb Z} U(p)$, where $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is obvious and $\mathbb Z \to U(p)$ sends $1 \mapsto k$.  Then, for any $\alpha$ as in the problem, define $\beta(r, x) = \alpha(r)x$.

Comment: @LSpice, I agree, thanks !

Comment: @LSpice Are there some thing missing in your comment? Are you sure about $\mathbb{Q}\times_Z  U(P)$.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But  I am not sure I can see an obvious answer for the second part. May be a slight modification of comment by @LSpice can give a complete answer

Comment: @AliTaghavi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371682/a-group-associated-to-a-pair-of-integers-k-p-where-p-is-a-prime-number/371711#comment940184_371711), everybody seems to have different notational conventions.  I [mean](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371682/a-group-associated-to-a-pair-of-integers-k-p-where-p-is-a-prime-number/371711#comment940084_371711) the pushout $(\mathbb Q \times U(p))/\langle(1, k^{-1})\rangle$.  It may be that no-one else uses this convention … maybe $\amalg_{\mathbb Z}$ would look better than $\times_{\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: The property defining universal groups is a bit strange, since it does not guarantee uniqueness (up to isomorphism). I think that if $\psi_{k,p}:\mathbb{Q} \to G_{k,p}$ satisfies the property, then for any group $G'$, the map $\psi'_{k,p}:\mathbb{Q} \to G_{k,p}\times G', \ q \mapsto (\psi_{k,p}(q),e_{G'})$ still satisfies the property. I think one should require $\psi_{k,p}$ to be surjective.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, would you be glad with an extension $\psi_{k,p}: \mathbb{Q} \to G_{k,p}$ of $\phi$ where $G_{k,p}$ contains the image of $\phi$ but not necessaryly $U(p)$?

Comment: @YvesStalder yes  this would be nice. BTW  according to your answer I realize that perhaps the problem relate to "extention of Charactets"

Comment: @YvesStalder, under [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371682/a-group-associated-to-a-pair-of-integers-k-p-where-p-is-a-prime-number/371711#comment940277_371711) condition, we could just take $G_{k, p} = \mathbb Q/e\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Q \times_{\mathbb Z} U(p)$, in which the image $\langle k + p\mathbb Z\rangle$ of $\phi$ embeds as $\mathbb Z/e\mathbb Z$, where $e$ is the order of $k$ modulo $p$.  Since any $\alpha$ is trivial on $e\mathbb Z$, the "lifting" $\beta$ in this case is just the obvious projection $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q/e\mathbb Z$.